# Search pdf manual for "brakes" indicator 1999 Toyota Camry

Tags: toyota, brakes, camry, indicators

The [CAMRY electrical pdf manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VffE36bxXwK5sTqal7aFe7CJmlxnc0kb/view?usp=sharing) is hundreds pages but is electronically searchable.

Full manual complement ([click here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qJBel-qm4wdVSFlWFLokHpxcZy6O56TP?usp=sharing))

The red "brakes" indicator on the dashboard is lit: several attempts to correct the indicator by disengaging the parking the brakes has failed.  I would like to lookup the troubleshooting procedure in the manuals, however, they are huge.

Is there a clever method to search the pdf file for the "brakes" dashboard indicator in the pdf files: the goal is to find information that would help to troubleshoot the red indicator.

## UPDATE

The car was stared, the parking brake was fully disengaged: the red "brakes" dashboard indicator was lit.  The brake fluid level sensor was disconnected:

[image]

and the 'brakes' indicator went dark.  Plugging in the harness in the photo lit the indicator.

When the sensor harness is disconnected, engaging the parking brake will light up the 'brakes' indicator (works as expected).  Thus it would seem that the problem is with the brake fluid sensor, as the fluid level is full.

Comment: Doesn’t that indicator also light if you are low on brake fluid, or if there is a problem with the ABS system?

Comment: If memory serves, the the brake fluid is not low.  I do not think the vehicle has ABS

Comment: You can see from PeteCon's posting, there are two inputs to the brake warning lamp.  Parking brake switch AND brake fluid level warning switch.  Either of those switches could be suspect, or the fluid is simply low.  "If memory serves..." Huh?  Checking brake fluid level visual check takes like 30 seconds.

Comment: @zipzit  Thanks for clarifying that there are 2 inputs to the brake warning dashboard indicator.   That really helps to narrow it down to inspecting / replacing switches (sensors).   I'll try to remember to report the inspection results, the next time I visit the relative and the car is in my custody.

Answer (score 2):

Look for 16."Inspect Parking Brake Switch"; That gives you the diagnostics. See screenshot of Page 51 in the pdf manual you posted; page 2271 in the bottom right corner of the manual.

The switch itself is down below the parking brake. Five minutes in a junk yard should turn up a good one if yours has failed.

[image]